# Foregound Service start action from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, foreground-service

I am working on an Android fall detection application. When user falls, alarm with timer turns on and if user not clik cancel within 15s, app send SMS to contact. Everything works fine when app is open but I don't know how my foreground service should work. Is it possible to make foreground service work like that- after fall detected foreground service open application and run timer from Main Activity?
Code from foreground service opening MainActivity:

```
Intent myIntent= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Yes. You'd need to keep it running during all times you wanted sensor information. You can start `Activities` from a foreground service as you please.

Comment: I already did foreground servis which open my Main Activity after fall detected but I don't know how to additionally start void from MainActivity. Can Youplease help me with that?

Below is my code from Foreground servic opening MainActivity

Comment: No, don't post an answer... edit your question. Or better yet, look up existing answers on SO. Also, see my comment on @HugoDjemaa's answer. Lastly, consider that you don't need an `Activity` to run a timer. You have execution via the foreground service.

Comment: I need Activity because my timer uses extends AppCompatActivity so I can't paste my code to Service

Comment: I didn't get why you dont simply run your timer on service. If your timer is an activity that extends AppCompatActivity, why you start MainActivity instead TimerActivity from service.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obstacles to your use case:

Firstly, starting from Android 10, there are [new restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) on starting an activity when your app is in the background (and as it's written on the android developer page, even with a foreground service, your app will be considered in the background if no activities are in foreground). So you won't be able to "pop" a view to the user, except if you target a version < 29 (but it's not very recommended).

Secondly, since the beginning of 2019, the Google Play Developer Policy [has been updated](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/) and you cannot use anymore the SEND_SMS permission, unless if you can justify in the publish console that your app is an SMS handler and you will need the user to register it as the default one. So you won't be able to send an automatic text message directly.

You can try to change the notification message to alert the user and try to have him click on the notification to open an activity.

Comment: Good answer, and I should point out something I missed in my comment: on API 29, one may need the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission to pop up an Activity, which requires the user to make a manual consent on the app's settings page.